# Need help converting get_user_meta [keys] into own array

Tags: wpdb

I have a plan to dynamically apply css values to elements on a page based on user specific meta data, so colors and page elements adjust based on what an individual user has seen/done before.

So I need to go from the array generated by

```
  $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $user_ID );
```

Which outputs like this

```
Array ( [nickname] => Array ( [0] => BigJoe) [first_name] => Array ( [0] => Joe) [last_name] => Array ( [0] => Bob) etc...
```

to a string of just the [$key] values

```
"nickname", "first_name" , "last_name" , etc..
```

then concatenate it (I guess with java) to a pattern of

```
'.' . '$key1' . ',''.' . '$key2' . ','
```

which would create a string of the css classes I'll echo into if-else scripts

```
.nickname, .last_name, .first_name, .etc,
```

What do you guys think? Could you please point me in a directions of functions I should research to get started?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the keys from array with this:

```
$keys = array_keys($all_meta_for_user);
```

Afterwards, implode your array to a string (inserting a dot before to create the first class):

```
$stringedKeys = '.'.implode(',.', $keys);
```

And now you have a string of keys that you can use in JS if you like, or insert them from PHP directly.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)